# laravel 5 mail::send() not working in controller

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

It show error while executing my code on server...

page not working on submit the form
Controller Code

```
class SaveFormController extends Controller {
public function create(){
    return view('/join-our-team');
}
public function store(SaveFormRequest $request){
    $data   =   Input::all();
    Mail::send('emails.reply', $data, function($message){
        $message->from($data['email'] , $data['name']);
        $message->to('abc@asd.com' , 'team');
    });
    return redirect('/');
 }
}
```

My html code was

```
<ul style="background: rgb(255, 210, 210);">
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>

    {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'applicant_store', 'class' => 'form')) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('Your Name') !!}
        {!! Form::text('name', null, 
            array('class'=>'form-control', 
                  'placeholder'=>'Your name')) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('Your E-mail Address') !!}
        {!! Form::text('email', null, 
            array('class'=>'form-control', 
                  'placeholder'=>'Your e-mail address')) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('Your Education') !!}
        {!! Form::select('education', ['Post Graduate', 'Graduate', '12th'], null, ['class'=>'form-control'] ) !!}
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('Your Contact No.') !!}
        {!! Form::text('phone', null, 
            array('class'=>'form-control', 
                  'placeholder'=>'Your 10 digit Mobile No.')) !!}
    </div>

    {!! Form::label('Experience') !!}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Years') !!}
            {!! Form::select('year',[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, '10+'],null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Months') !!}
            {!! Form::select('month',[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('Resume (doc,docx,pdf format)') !!}
        {!! Form::file('applicant_resume',['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Submit Details', 
          array('class'=>'btn btn-success')) !!}
    </div>                      

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

and my app/mail.php configuration is

```
<?php
return [
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.abc.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => ['address' => 'my_mail', 'name' => 'team'],
'encryption' => 'tls',
'username' => env('my_email'),
'password' => env('my_pwd'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
];
```

Cannot found the error after try diffetrent......
Please help me to get the solution..

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: The general syntax from laravel. Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Comment: Can you turn debug on in Laravel and repeat to see the error

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the data you're passing to the mail function.  The second parameter is for the data that is being sent to the view not within the function.  Change it to this

```
public function store(SaveFormRequest $request){
    $data   =   Input::all();
    Mail::send('emails.reply', $data, function($message) use($data) {
        $message->from($data['email'] , $data['name']);
        $message->to('abc@asd.com' , 'team');
    });
    return redirect('/');
```

Answer (score 0):

if your html code and controller are ok than you just need to ..change the  file with like this...

config/mail.php

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mail'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'www.yourdomain.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => ['address' => 'info@domain.com', 'name' => name'],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
```

and change the .env file to

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=www.yourdomain.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=email address
MAIL_PASSWORD=your email plassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

hope so it will work